# How do I edit the Bot Code c# after its published in Azure

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I created a bot in the Azure bot framework.  It's a Qna one.

It works, I can see it in the webchat, I can see it in my bots of bot framework page, I can see the qna data source in qnamaker.

When I go to azure and look at the resources and click on my bot service, it takes me to the Create Page,  well I don't want to create, I want to get to the code of the existing bot, I can't figure out how, some of the props are editable in the bot framework site, but not the code.

I did not configure continuous integration. Or download the code as it was boiler plate, but I want to poke at it now.

Comment: Are you using Azure Bot Service?  You can find many bot examples here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples

Comment: @BinaryJam What is your Bot Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this problem.

Once you have closed all your windows and want to return to your bot, if you find that you seeing the Create Application ID screen and not the bot details screen with the code, channels and analytics bit, then you have opened this is IE11,

Ditch the crappy browser and open it in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the update, glad to hear you found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Develop with Azure Bot Service > Set up continuous integration](https://web.archive.org/web/20170629125643/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure/azure-bot-service-continuous-integration)

1. Within your Azure bot, click the Settings tab and expand the Continuous integration section.
2. Click the link to download the zip file that contains the source code for your bot.
3. Extract the contents of the downloaded zip file to the local folder where you are planning to sync your deployment source.
   [image: Download code from Bot Service settings page]
   <sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/media/continuous-integration-download.png))</sub>

Comment: Thats only available on furst vist subsequent visits dont show me that screen I need to get there

Comment: Hey @BinaryJam what screen do you see on subsequent visits? and what is your botid?

Comment: Hi each time I click on the bot service I only get the creaae screen the one thats asks for ids. I dont want to create a new one just edit the existing one.  Dont know bot id. Well wont find out till I get back to work.